# Setting XSLT variables within for-each select

Tags: xslt

Good Day,

I have an XSLT template I'm assembling that look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CarParts/Items">
<div class="columns"><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></div>
<div class="columns"><xsl:value-of select="Amount"/></div>
<div class="columns">[SUBTOTAL]</div><br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I know that I can define an XSLT variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="totalAmount" select="sum(CarParts/Items/Amount)" />
```

But I want my XSLT variable to be [SUBTOTAL] which is equal to Quantity * Amount *within* the for-each select loop.  Is this possible?  If this was SQL, this would be the equivalent of a computed column.

Any suggestions?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is cast the value to a number, then you can multiply it as desired:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <results>
            <xsl:for-each select="CarParts/Items">
                <Item id="{position()}">
                    <q><xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></q>
                    <a><xsl:value-of select="Amount"/></a>
                    <st><xsl:value-of select="number(Quantity)*number(Amount)"/></st>
                </Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </results>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I changed the formatting a little since there was no provided input/CSS, but you should see what I was going for. Running it on my sample input of

```
<CarParts>
  <Items>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Amount>100.00</Amount>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Amount>25.00</Amount>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
  </Items>
</CarParts>
```

I get the result of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<results>
    <Item id="1">
        <q>1</q>
        <a>100.00</a>
        <st>100</st>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2">
        <q>2</q>
        <a>25.00</a>
        <st>50</st>
    </Item>
    <Item id="3">
        <q>3</q>
        <a>6</a>
        <st>18</st>
    </Item>
</results>
```

Comment: Yes, this does.  But what is the significance of define your own <q>, <a>, and <st> tags.  It looks like you're using this just to control your output data so that it appears between those tags, right?

Comment: You are correct, that was my quick way to have a formatted output for the quantity, amount, and subtotal elements.